# Menu staying on top covers top lines of text

Tags: css

I am creating a menu bar with `w3-css`. The menu bar should be fixed to the top.

Here is an example, please try to decrease screen width:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEZ9Z1BYNTEX

The problem is, when screen width is set to narrow, and the menu wraps into more than one lines, it covers the first lines of text. Is there a way to solve it somehow?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. The link can become invalid

Comment: Well, resize the elements, hide the search input field using a button, use the hamburger icon for the dropdown menu, etc. There are various ways to save space in a smaller viewport...

Comment: Improve question formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using a media query. Media queries allow you to apply CSS to a site at a certain screen size. For example:

```
  @media (max-width: 650px) {
       .w3-container {
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
  }
```

This CSS pushes the container down at smaller screen sizes so that the menu will never cover up the text below it. Alternatively you could use a media query to make the menu text smaller or hide certain parts of your menu when it gets to smaller sizes.

Most people switch to another form of menu for mobile devices such as a Hamburger menu. This isnt needed to fix the problem you are currently facing but you might want to look into it for your future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Set .w3-top to position sticky instead of fixed. Then remove margin-top from the body.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOC96ENPLRNO